# Error C2039 - is not a member of std::basic_string

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Please note, that I did add a header file strutils.h, also I copied this file in the project. strutils.cpp was added to the Source Files and was also copied into the Project folder.

**The Error I receive is as follows: error C2039: 'ToLower' : is not a member of 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>'
**

I started the code following the book Computer Science Tapestry by Astrachan, I did check the book several times, but no result on my part. (The library strutils does include ToLower() function)

I feel that I am missing something very simple.

Below is my code.

```
    #ifndef _STRUTILS_H
    #define _STRUTILS_H

    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include "strutils.h"
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
         string boot = "Drimmnal";
         boot.ToLower();

         cin.ignore();
         cin.get();
         return 0;
    }

     #endif
```

Comment: Please learn C++ systematically from a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), or badness like this code will keep haunting you and your colleagues.

Comment: The message means that `ToLower` isn't a member of `std::string`, of which `boot` is an instance. Read [a good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: @GunCode: Read your book again, the signature for that function is `void ToLower(string & s);`. It's not a `std::string` member function and it doesn't take two numeric parameters.

Comment: @Blastfurnace The two Parameters are a result of series of debugging on my part. Removing them does not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are trying to use is **not** a member function of the Standard Library `std::string` class so you can't call it by saying `boot.ToLower()`. That syntax is reserved for member functions.

This function is provided in the support materials for your book. It has a signature of `void ToLower(string & s);`. It's a free function that takes a `std::string` *by reference* and, I assume, changes the string in place. You'll want to call it like any other free function and pass it a `std::string` variable.

Change:

```
boot.ToLower();
```

To:

```
ToLower(boot);
```

---

In addition, you want to remove the following lines from your source code:

```
#ifndef _STRUTILS_H
#define _STRUTILS_H
```

and

```
#endif
```

These lines are include guards from the `strutils.h` file and I'm not sure why they are in your source file.